# Composite limit function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am trying to prove the following result. This is how far I got. I can't find it anywhere.

Thorem: If $f(x)$ is continuous at $L$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=L$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(g(x)=f\left(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\right)=f(L)$.

Proof: Assume $f(x)$ is continuous at a point $L$, and that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=L$.

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0:[|x-L|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(L)\bigr|<\varepsilon]$.

And $\forall\delta>0,\exists\delta'>0:[|x-a|<\delta'\implies|g(x)-L<\delta]$.

So, $\forall\delta>0,\exists\delta'>0:[|x-a|<\delta'\implies|f(g(x))-f(L)|<\epsilon]$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=L$ so $f(\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x))=f(L)$.

I think I am questioning the validity of the correlation between my second and third statements, but I am not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The proof also follows from sequential continuity: we have that for any $x_n \to L$ then $f(x_n) \to f(L)$. Also, by assumption for any $y_n \to a$ then $g(y_n) \to L$ (a sequential limit criterion). But since $g(y_n)$ is a sequence converging to $L$, then $f(g(y_n)) \to f(L)$. I think this is more immediate than with using $\epsilon - \delta$ arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the right thing but the way you've presented it is a bit confusing. Why not word it like this: Pick $\epsilon > 0$. Continuity of $f$ at $L$ gives you an $\eta$ such that $|x - L| < \eta \implies |f(x) - f(L)| < \epsilon$. For this $\eta$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x) = L$ gives you a $\delta$ such that $|x-a| < \delta \implies |g(x) - L| < \eta$.

Hence $|x-a| < \delta \implies |g(x) - L| < \eta \implies |f(g(x)) - f(L)| < \epsilon$.